# use serverless to get instance's status

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, serverless-framework

i am new to serverless framework and i want to get an instance's status, so i used  boto3 `describe-instance-status()` but i keep getting error that i am not authorized to perform this kind of operation althought i have administrator access to all aws services; please help, do i need to change, or add something to be recognized

here is my code :

```
import json
import boto3
import logging
import sys

#setup simple logging for INFO
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def  instance_status(event, context):
"""Take an instance Id and return its status"""
#print "ttot"
body = {}
status_code = 200
client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=['i-070ad071'])

return response
```

and here is my serverless.yml file

```
service: ec2 
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  timeout: 30
  memorySize: 128
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
          - "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus"
      Resource: "*"


functions:
  instance_status:
    handler: handler.instance_status
    description: Status ec2 instances

events:
  - http:
      path: ''
      method: get
```

and here is the error message i am getting:

> "errorType": "ClientError",   "errorMessage": "An error occurred
>   (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstanceStatus
>   operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation."

Comment: You are using lambda? What is your lambda's IAM Role using? That IAM Role has permission to perform EC2's resource? double check permission of this role.

Comment: i did not specify a role, could i do this in serverless.yml ? witch role is the most convinient to work with boto3 library

Comment: Please share your IAM policy attached with the role.

Answer (score 1):

> ...i have administrator access to all aws services...

Take note that the Lambda function is NOT running under your user account. You're supposed to define its role and permissions in your YAML.

In the `provider` section in your `serverless.yaml`, add the following:

```
iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus
    Resource: <insert your resource here>
```

Reference: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/

Comment: i did the same thing, but don't know why i keep getting the same error

Comment: Update your `serverless.yml` in your original question then. Maybe the `Resource` is incorrect? Or the indentation?

Comment: i just did, please if it s not too much asking, can you check if it's correct

Comment: LGTM. Did you redeploy? When do you get the error, during deployment or when calling the HTTP endpoint? Double-check what's in the Lambda console.

Comment: i get error when calling the http endpoint, in the Lambda Console, it runs perfectly, i get the instance 's status with no problem, i have checked the configuration area, and i have the following Role :

Comment: ec2-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole

Comment: Now, i am getting this error message {"message": "Internal server error"}

Answer (score 0):

> You are not authorized to perform this operation

This means you have no permission to perform this action `client.describe_instance_status`.

There some ways to make your function can get right permission:

1. Use IAM Role: Create IAM Role with permission accroding to your requirement. Then assign this IAM role for lambda function in the setting page. So your lambda will automatic get rotate key to perform actions.
2. Create AccessKey/SecretKey with permission accroding to your requirement. Setting in yaml file, in your lambda function, set boto3 to accquire these access/secretKey, then perform action.

Read more from this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html

Comment: i did change role by hand in the aws console to have access at boto3, it works fine in the aws console, but when i test it with the http end point it gives me {"message": "Internal server error"} so i think that i need to add something to my serverless.yml file, but don't know how to do it using serverless